# Autoform bootstrap themes

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, radio-button, meteor-autoform

I'm using aldeed's autoform, simpleschema and collection2. I am looking to change the way the radio buttons / check boxes look. I've read through the documentation but am unable to find how to incorporate different ways how the buttons are visually rendered. On the GIT issue page, I read through how to implement custom class in the schema itself. Example:

```
"type":{
        type: String,
        autoform:{
            type: "select-radio-inline",
            class: "radio-primary",
            options: function(){
                return [
                    {label: "Well Known", value: "well-known"},
                    {label: "Basic", value: "basic"},
                    {label: "Extended", value: "extended"}
                ];
            },
```

But somehow it does not change the look of the default radio buttons. Is there a workaround for this?